# underline word in angular template

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

How do I underline the words "this" and "note" without breaking the words up or modifying the actual sliderNote?

JS:

```
$scope.sliderNote="This is my note";
```

Html:

```
<div class="sliderNote">
      {{sliderNote}}
      </div>
```

css:

```
.sliderNote {
  font-size:12px;
  color:gray;

}
```

Comment: Why don't you want to break the words up?

Comment: because what if I have a paragraph. I have other variables which have long text

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you want to do? Do you want to underline the first and last word, or every occurrence of a word, or words at certain indices?

Comment: in this case, I want to underline the word "this" and the word "note". But if I have a paragraph, I want to underline only specific words

Answer (score 1):

you can achieve this by creating a custom filter

in the script define the controller and filter

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.sliderNote="This is my note";
  $scope.selectedWords = ["This","note"];
});

app.filter("underline", function($sce){
    return function(txt, phrase){
       if(phrase instanceof Array){
          if(txt === undefined){
             return;
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < phrase.length; i++) {
            var key = phrase[i];
          txt = txt.replace(new RegExp('('+key+')', 'gi'),'<span style="text-decoration: underline;">$1</span>');
        };  
       }
    return $sce.trustAsHtml(txt);
  };
});
```

in the view use data-ng-bind-html

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html ng-app="app">

 <head>
  <script  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.7/angular.min.j s"></script>
</head>

 <body ng-controller="mainCtrl">
   <div class="sliderNote" data-ng-bind-html="sliderNote | underline :  selectedWords">

 </body>
 </html>
```

Plunker : http://plnkr.co/edit/fLSzpvWwFXQaAs5dcjBf?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

You could create a filter which you could apply to `{{ slideNote | underline:'this,note' }}`.

You would take the input into the filter from `slideNote`, take the words to highlight from the `'this,note'` parameter, split the string into the words and then wrap any of those words inside your input string with a `<u></u>` tag.

Finally, you'd return the output of the filter and make sure you set the filter to be marked safe so that the HTML won't be escaped.

Filter documentation can be found here https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter

Answer (score 0):

Use ng-bind-html with a function that takes as input your paragraph and returns the html with undelined words:

```
<div class="sliderNote" ng-bind-html="underlineWords(sliderNote)">

      </div>
```

JS:

```
$scope.sliderNote="This is my note";

$scope.underlineWords = function (text){
    text.replace(" this ", " <u>this</u> ");
    text.replace(" note ", " <u>note</u> ");
    return text;
}
```

Comment: could you just give an example of how I would surroudn the words with <u>?

Comment: text.replace("word", "<u>word</u>")

Comment: or text.replace(" word ", " <u>word</u> "), with spaces to make sure the word is not a substring of a longer word.

Comment: and also, do I not need the {{sliderNote}} under that div?